# VectorDrawable on ImageButton is ugly

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design, android-vectordrawable

I've the following `ImageButton`:

```xml
<ImageButton xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fireButton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_whatshot_48px"
    android:tint="@color/accent"
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:onClick="fire" />
```

The `ic_whatshot_48px` is a `VectorDrawable`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="48dp"
    android:height="48dp"
    android:viewportWidth="48"
    android:viewportHeight="48">

    <path
        android:fillColor="#000000"
        android:pathData="M27 1.34s1.48 5.3 1.48 9.6c0 4.12-2.7 7.47-6.83
7.47s-7.25-3.34-7.25-7.47l.05-.72C10.43 15.03 8 21.23 8 28c0 8.84 7.16 16 16
16s16-7.16 16-16c0-10.79-5.19-20.41-13-26.66zM23.42 38c-3.56
0-6.45-2.81-6.45-6.28 0-3.25 2.09-5.53 5.63-6.24s7.2-2.41 9.23-5.15c.78 2.58
1.19 5.3 1.19 8.07 0 5.29-4.3 9.6-9.6 9.6z" />
</vector>
```

But the image is scaled and is blured and ugly.

[image: Ugly VectorDrawable screenshot]

Why is that? It's `VECTORDrawable`, it should be nice and smooth.

Comment: Can we see the `VectorDrawable` code?

Comment: maybe it's because your SVG is 48x48px?

Comment: Yes, you can. I added it to the question. I know I can change `width`, `height` anbd viewport, but I don't know on which screen will the app run, so I can't use exact numbers. I want Android to do that. :)

Comment: So it's not as scalable as advertised? :(

Comment: It doesn't really say scalable. Nor is it a vector graphic like you would think. It lets you have a plot of points and draw it to what predefined size you would like. You should be using densities for your drawables to make images appear pretty on all device (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi...)

Comment: You could try changing the viewport width/height and scaling the pathDAta up but I don't think it will make much difference

Comment: It's a framework issue with how vector drawables are cached. This has been fixed for a future release.

Comment: @alanv When you say "It's a framework issue", would that also affect the 3rd party backwards compatible VectorDrawable libraries?

Comment: This question is newer [VectorDrawable is scaled and unsharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34090427/vectordrawable-is-scaled-and-unsharp), but has a pretty good explananation about why this happens.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is too late to answer this but there might be other people who have the same problem.

The problem is due to the width and height in Vector definition. You set it to low value set it to a higher value and you are done.

If you want to use it for multi-screen sizes, then you need to do something like this:

```
<vector ...
        android:width="@dimen/vector_size"
        android:height="@dimen/vector_size"
        .../>
```

Then defining this in res/values:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="vector_size">24dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

For more information on why you need to give width and height for vectors, read this:

[Understanding Android's VectorDrawable properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30233771/animatedvectordrawable-animate-programmatically-in-runtime?rq=1)

Comment: That's not true. It should be working as using srcCompat in an ImageView. You are talking about the default size.