# Add animation at run time

Tags: android, xml, animation, android-vectordrawable

I want to animate my `AnimatedVectorDrawable` at runtime without using `.xml` files. Actually I'm using `.xml` files same way as documentation's samples shows:

[AnimatedVectorDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawable.html)

So, I have  `vector_drawable.xml` contains`<vector>` with nested `<group>` and `<path>` which defines a shape.

For this vector I have `animated_vector_drawable.xml` contains `<animated-vector>` with `android:animation` assinged to `<target>`.

Last step is define an animation file `rotation.xml` using `<objectAnimator>` which is used by `animated_vector_drawable.xml`

Everything works fine, but the problem appears, when I need to create many different shapes (vectors) with many different or similar animations, because this generate many `.xml` files.

1. I can't include ready and prepared `<vector>` from one `.xml` file to another (some kind of `<include>` tag) so i need to copy the same code to another files. It is very annoying.
2. If I want to use the same animation for few `<target>` elements but each animation must have f.e. different delay or any property value (`alpha`, `rotation`, `interpolator`...) , I must create new `.xml` file contains `<objectAnimator>` with changed one property value instead of use the same, one file with changed property value. It's also annoying.
3. I discovered that I can use `ObjectAnimator` and set `alpha` & `fillColor` for `AnimatedVectorDrawable` but there is a problem when I want to change it's `translateX`, `translateY`, `rotation` or any other properties. Is there a way to do this without `.xml`. I just want to have access to `<group>`

Comment: How do you do this "I discovered that I can use ObjectAnimator and set alpha & fillColor for AnimatedVectorDrawable programmatically "

Comment: Yes. I'd also love to know how to access the ObjectAnimator programatically here.

Comment: I'm also interested to know if there's a solution to this

Comment: Hi @Wisnia You can find some use case and code snippet  https://github.com/pathikdevani/Vaividhya-2k15-Android-And-Server/blob/5b2c5db0d3cbc6e0aa2276c95734a5ddac30b5a9/android/app/src/main/java/com/spidren/ui/drawer/DrawerDataLayout.java#L83

Answer (score 0):

Constructor that you used creates animation with absolute values (pixels).

```
TranslateAnimation in = new TranslateAnimation(
Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 1.0f,
Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, 0, 0.0f, 0, 0.0f);
```

Try use Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT to fit your needs.