# VectorDrawable is scaled and unsharp

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

**Vector xml in Android Studio:**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="24dp"
android:height="24dp"
android:viewportHeight="24.0"
android:viewportWidth="24.0">
<path
    android:fillColor="#FF000000"
    android:pathData="M12,15C7.58,15 4,16.79 4,19V21H20V19C20,16.79 16.42,15 12,15M8,9A4,4 0,0 0,12 13A4,4 0,0 0,16 9M11.5,2C11.2,2 11,2.21 11,2.5V5.5H10V3C10,3 7.75,3.86 7.75,6.75C7.75,6.75 7,6.89 7,8H17C16.95,6.89 16.25,6.75 16.25,6.75C16.25,3.86 14,3 14,3V5.5H13V2.5C13,2.21 12.81,2 12.5,2H11.5Z" />
```

**The result:**

[image]

**Changing `24dp` to `96dp`, result:**

[image]

**Menu xml in Android Studio:**

```
...
<!-- Sperren -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/suppress_button"
    style="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialSheetFab.Sheet.Item"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_assignment_return"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_assignment_return"
    android:text="Sperren" />

 <!-- IH-Auftrag -->
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/setup_maintenance_order_button"
    style="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialSheetFab.Sheet.Item"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_ih_auftraege"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_ih_auftraege"
    android:text="IH-Auftrag" />
    ...
```

So my question now is, how to change the size automatically like a svg normally should do?

Comment: What version of Android are you testing on?

Comment: It's occurring under Android 4.4.4 and 5.0.2

Comment: Well, Android 4.4 doesn't have native `VectorDrawable` support, so there you're definitely looking at some bitmap, built by the developer tools from the vector XML.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but I have really no idea how to do that..

Comment: You might want to use **true svg** files (`VectorDrawables` are a subset). And use a **free** third party library ([android-svg](https://github.com/BigBadaboom/androidsvg) or [svg-android](https://github.com/applantation/svg-android), to name a couple) to open, scale and convert them to bitmaps.

Answer (score 6):

I am not quite sure this is the answer you were looking for, but here it goes anyway:

**In short:** use `ImageView` with `scaleType="fitXY"` and set up the size you want or create your own subclass and set dimensions on the `Drawable` as described below.

`ImageView` with the same vector drawable, scale type is `fitCenter` on the left, `fitXY` on the right:

[image: ImageView example]

**Long description of the issue:**

Your problem might come from the fact that numerous Android components are using `Drawable` instance assuming it has static dimensions.
These components are trying to get the actual dimensions of the `Drawable` by calling [Drawable#getIntrinsicHeight()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#getIntrinsicHeight()) and [Drawable#getIntrinsicWidth()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#getIntrinsicWidth()). These methods will serve the exact amounts you have defined in your `VectorDrawable` resource as height and width respectively.
If these dimensions do not fit the required dimensions of the rectangle where the rendering goes then (usually) these components are applying a scaling `Matrix` on the `Canvas` before rendering the `Drawable`. The `Drawable` doesn't know anything about that it must be rendered into different dimension and renders the vector into a `Bitmap` with the dimensions you defined in the resource. After the `Bitmap` is ready with the vector content it will be rendered to the `Canvas` using scaling and (no surprise) it gets blurry.

Not all components are doing this luckily, for example `ImageView` is able to tell the `Drawable` that it needs to be rendered into different dimensions by calling [Drawable#setBounds()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#setBounds(int, int, int, int)), but only if the scale type is set to [FitXY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html#FIT_XY). *(I had to peek into `ImageView` sources to figure this out.)*
Unfortunately, this might not help in some cases. You can create your own subclassed component from these OS components and set the dimensions on the `Drawable` when you figure out the right dimensions.

Comment: This is a great observation. I'll add some extra information. If you are using the AppCompat support library (currently 23.2.0) to use the Vector Drawable support library then the behaviour is slightly different. For API 21+ it's as you describe above, only fitXY will scale properly. However if you run it on an API 20 or below device then other scaleTypes will work too, I've tried fitCenter, centerCrop and fitEnd. In practice unfortunately that means only fitXY is really useful for this purpose as it works on both.

Comment: Interesting. Sounds like Google devs figured out that this is an unintended behaviour and fixed it in the support lib. Probably it will be fixed in N too, not that it would help too much for the next 5 years or so... As it seems you are right and we have to stick with FitXY. :/